# How can I load font-lock-add-keywords on restart?

Tags: font-lock

I use desktop session. Every time I restart my TODOS won't
appear unless I kill the buffer and open it again.

```lisp
;; SESSION
(setq desktop-save-mode t
      desktop-save t
      desktop-save-buffer t
      desktop-saved-frameset t
      desktop-restore-frames t
      tab-bar-mode t
      tab-bar-show 1)

;; TODOS: This don't show up on unless I kill the buffer and open it.
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my/keywords)
(defun my/keywords ()
"My Font Lock Keywords."
(interactive)
      (font-lock-add-keywords
        nil '(("\\<\\(\\(FIX\\(ME\\)?\\|TODO 1\\|BUG\\):\\)" 1  'org-mode-line-clock-overrun t)
                                ("\\(README:\\)" 1 '(face nil display ""))
                                ("\\<\\(\\(TIP\\):\\)" 1  '(:background "#99c3ff" :foreground "black") t)
                                ("\\<\\(\\(TODO 2\\|TODOS\\):\\)" 1  '(:background "#5f875f" :foreground "white") t)
                                ("\\<\\(\\(HACK\\):\\)" 1  font-lock-warning-face prepend)
                                ("\\<\\(\\(INFO\\):\\)" 1  '(:background "#2563EB" :foreground "white") t)
                                ("\\<\\(\\(WARN\\|WARNING\\):\\)" 1  '(:background "#ff9933" :foreground "black") t)
                                ("===\\(|? \\(.*\\) |?\\)===" 1  '(:background "" :foreground "#57a5e5") t)
                                ("\\(\\(│\\|╭\\|╰\\).*$\\)" 1  '(:background "" :foreground "#57a5e5") t)
                                ("\\<\\(\\(TODO\\|FUTURE\\):\\)" 1  '(:background "#404040" :foreground "white") t)
)))
```

Comment: Do you mean buffers that are automatically reopened by Emacs when you start it, using "desktop save"? Is there a specific place in your init file where you load the desktop? If so, make sure your hook is installed before the desktop is loaded.

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks, looks like you solved it :D . So, by the looks of it hooks need to come before. What I ended up doing is moved my desktop session stuff to the end of the init.el which solved it. If you want to answer with something along the lines of "add hooks before desktop.." I will choose it as best answer. Thanks